# DAX Formula for Attachment in Market Basket Analysis using Power Pivot 2013

Tags: powerpivot, dax, market-basket-analysis

I am trying to write a formula for calculating the total attached sales revenue of product B, which is attached to product A. 
But the formula below gives me the attached sales revenue for product A instead of B. Details of the formula are also below. 
****Help Please.****

=CALCULATE(SUM([SALES_AMT]),CALCULATETABLE(SUMMARIZE(Sales,[GLOBAL_CONTRACT_ID]),ALL(Product),USERELATIONSHIP(Sales[SKU_NUM],'Filter Product'[Filter SKU NO])))

Sales revenue is in table "Sales" Column "SALES_AMT" & unique id used for calculation is "GLOBAL_CONTRACT_ID"

Product A is in table "PRODUCT" & Product B is in table "Filter Product".

Table "Sales" is in Active relation to table "PRODUCT" via "SKU_NUM"

Table "Sales" is in In-Active relation to table "Filter Product" via "Filter SKU NO"

Comment: See if this helps you http://blog.gbrueckl.at/2014/02/applied-basket-analysis-in-power-pivot-using-dax/

Comment: Thanks for the help, I Tried the above link before, it didn't work. I m trying to find the sales revenue of product B which is attached to product A, but using the above logic i end up getting sales revenue of product A instead of B.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the sales of B but only where it is in a 'transaction' that contains A?

Comment: Hi Jacob, Yes you are correct, i want only the sales revenue of product B where it is in a "transaction" containing product A also.